# Реализация размещения префабов в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Идея в том, чтобы сделать "генератор" карты, т.е у меня есть точки и префабы комнат. Нужно создать скрипт, который будет размещать комнаты на точке, т.е на одной точке при включении может заспавниться одна комната, а потом другая (при другом включении).
Подскажите с чего начать, и/или дать какую-то информацию об этом.
Я использую Unity3d 2022.3.18